# How to delete PK and file in FileField django?

Tags: django, database, models

I have a `modelform` with a `FileField`, so I just add some files with some descriptions for my database. It adds a file in the location I have defined in `MEDIA_ROOT` and adds a PK for each item. For example consider that I add 5 objects with 5 files.

My problem is that when I delete all 5 objects, from shell or admin, the corresponding files and PKs won't be deleted, And when I add another object, the PK starts from 6. How can I completely delete an object with its corresponding file and PK and sort the others, for example if I delete the 3rd object, I want that the 4th and 5th objects, became 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't actually delete a Primary Key from your tables.
Tables are index by their row ids. meaning that if you delete a row, the id of the row would be unavailable to use later on. Otherwise every time a row gets deleted, then the hole table should be reindexed which take a lot of time and resources considering how much rows you have in your table.

But you can do it anyway.
The way it's done is that you have to make another column as an extra id column and index the table with it.
Also you have to change all the ids after you delete a row.
I highly recommend you not to do this because i don't see how you can benefit from such an architecture for your database.

And for deleting the file when you delete a row:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=YourModel)
def file_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.YOUR_FILE_FIELD_NAME: 
        instance.YOUR_FILE_FIELD_NAME.delete()
```

It will delete the saved file anytime you delete a row from anywhere.

Or this way:

```
os.remove('file/path')
```